# Canvas drawImage using the position of div on top of image

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is on top of the image. I have to get the image content which is inside the overlaying div and draw using canvas.

The problem I am facing is, I am not able to draw the correct image. I have to programmatically get the correct image below the div.

The image below shows the comparison of the original image and drawn image in canvas.

[image]

Below is my code which drawsImage by taking the coordinates of the div:

```
  DrawImage() {
var canvas: any = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvasRef = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var imagemarker = document.getElementById("imagemarker");
var markerRef = imagemarker.getBoundingClientRect();

var img = document.getElementById("myimage");

ctx.drawImage(
  img,
  markerRef.left,
  markerRef.top,
  markerRef.width,
  markerRef.height,
  0,
  0,
  canvasRef.width,
  canvasRef.height
);
}
```

And the html code to display image and canvas element:

```
<button (click)="DrawImage()">Draw</button>
  <div id="imagemarkercontainer">
    <div id="imagemarker"></div>
  </div>
  <img id="myimage" src="https://imgur.com/NWQo2xk.jpeg" width="300px" 
     height="250px">
   <br>
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300px" height="250px" style="border:1px 
      solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

I have attached a stackblitz example that shows the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4untgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add relevant part of the code to the question. You can copy the canvas drawing part of code from stackblitz and paste here.

Comment: @sabithpocker Added the html and javascript code to the question

Comment: @abhilashreddy you need to take care of natural width & height of image to crop on canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care of `img` bounding rect and also `natural` width & height of image.

As you are setting image width & height, get `naturalWidth` and calculate proportional width as below

```
var imgRef = img.getBoundingClientRect();
var nWidth = img.naturalWidth;
var nHeight = img.naturalHeight;


ctx.drawImage(
  img,
  ( markerRef.left - imgRef.left) * nWidth /img.width ,
  ( markerRef.top -imgRef.top) * nHeight / img.height ,
  markerRef.width * nWidth /img.width,
  markerRef.height * nHeight / img.height ,
  0,
  0,
  canvasRef.width,
  canvasRef.height
);
```

[Here is working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oakquz)

Comment: I have been trying with properties like offset top, offset left, didn't know about natural width and height. Thank you so much yogen.